# jQuery from HTML page posting to WCF web service confusion

Tags: jquery, json, wcf

A newbie here with a jQuery/AJAX issue.
Basically, I want to post a simple string (eg. "4,5") to a WCF web service that takes the string and creates a table, then sends the table back to the browser.
I've created and tested the WCF web service and invoked w/ the built in VS2012 client. No problems - string in, table out - works perfectly.

On the client side (an HTML page with jQuery in this case), I'm not so lucky.
Following an example of POSTing from a tutorial, I've found that WCF doesn't accept JQuery's POSTing data type and I get the following error in my browser debugger:

```
[14:02:36.071] POST http://localhost:58291/Service1.svc [HTTP/1.1 415 Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'. 4ms]
```

I did some looking around and found, either I change the WCF service side (which I can locally, but this is for someone else, so that's not an option!) OR I can change the jQuery code (which is what I want to do).

When I change the contentType on the JQuery side to 'text/xml' I then get a "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request" error.

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:58291/Service1.svc/GetHTMLTableFromDimensionString',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'text/xml',
        data: dimselection,
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
```

The var dimselection is a string from a dropdown , though I've tried creating a JSON version {"strDims",dimselection} in the data: block with no luck. , but the error message is saying that it is a Bad Request appears to mean that the data is still in the wrong format - strings nor JSON work.
I found another post saying WCF is REST and another SOAP (which one is it really? how can I poll a WCF web service to find out what data it needs?)
Am I calling the service wrong? Formatting the data wrong? A specifier missing?

Comment: WCF is SOAP and can do REST as well, though people are probably moving to Web API for RESTful services.  How big is the data you're trying to send?  It might be too big for the service's quota and that would generate a bad request response.

Comment: in the test client, I found the XML output - indeed, it's SOAP.
The output is an HTML TABLE with 2-10 rows and 2-10 columns.
I may just tell them to use a standard aspx page with querystrings - it works 10x faster - 0 delays, no goofy formatting (after all, what is a web service but a web page?)

Comment: OK, I'm going through different jQuery/SOAP tutorials online (I found only 1 so far on Google - most are via ASMX or using ScriptManager instead of jQuery). More experimenting is in order (once I figure this Pandora's Box out, I'll write a book titled "jQuery & WCF for complete idiots" and make millions!)

Answer (score 0):

Can you try

```
data:'{"strDims":"4,5"}',
contentType:"application/json",
dataType:"json",
```

Also pls make sure that the [WebInvoke] decorator is added to the method you are invoking as it is a POST request.

```
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
                 BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
                 ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
                 RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
```

Comment: I'll give that a try here in the next few days - I was having so much trouble w/WCF, I used a standard aspx page for the service for a proof of concept.